# Canceling an independent task

Tags: c#, task, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

I need to spawn multiple tasks having in mind that I could add more tasks through a SignalR hub later on. Those tasks should be named, so I can search for a specific task. Each of these tasks should be able to be canceled independently (separate `CancellationTokenSource`).

Questions:

- Is there a different collection that I can use?
- Can I improve my code in any way?

```cs
public interface IMyClass
{
    void Start(string name);
    void Stop(string name);
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private List<Tuple<string, Task, CancellationTokenSource>> _tasks = new List<Tuple<string, Task, CancellationTokenSource>>();

    public void Start(string name)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(name, cts.Token));
        _tasks.Add(new Tuple<string, Task, CancellationTokenSource>(name, task, cts));
    }

    public void Stop(string name)
    {
        foreach (var tuple in _tasks)
        {
            if (tuple.Item1.Contains(name))
            {
                CancellationTokenSource cts = tuple.Item3;
                cts.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }

    public void DoWork(string name, CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{name} is working");

                // long operation...
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{name} canceled");
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If code is working, your best bet maybe is to post over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, thanks. I didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks fine, but you may consider if it is allowed to use the same task name twice.
And instead of

```
private List<Tuple<string, Task, CancellationTokenSource>> _tasks = new List<Tuple<string, Task, CancellationTokenSource>>();
```

you could use a dictionary

```
private Dictionary<string,Tuple<Task, CancellationTokenSource>> _tasks = new Dictionary<string,Tuple<Task, CancellationTokenSource>>();
```

I would personally wrap the information about the task in a new type, that makes it easier to maintain and add new features later. Something like this:

```
public class TaskInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Task Task { get; set; }
    public CancellationTokenSource Token { get; set; }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public interface IMyClass
{
    void Start(string name);
    void Stop(string name);
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private Dictionary<string,TaskInfo> _tasks = new Dictionary<string,TaskInfo>();

    public void Start(string name)
    {
        if(_tasks.ContainsKey(name)) 
            throw new Exception($"Task with name {name} already exists");

        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        TaskInfo taskInfo = new TaskInfo() {
            Token = cts,
            Name = name,
            Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(name, cts.Token))
        };

        _tasks.Add(name,taskInfo);
    }

    public void Stop(string name)
    {
        if (_tasks.ContainsKey(name)) {
            _tasks[name].Token.Cancel();
        }
    }

    public void DoWork(string name, CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{name} is working");

                // long operation...
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{name} canceled");
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

this may not be a better solution, but i prefer an approach like this